# How do i transcode all files in a directory with ffmpeg

Tags: scripts, ffmpeg

I am wanting to make a script to transcode all the lossless files from my camera to 3mb/s and change the codec to h.264. I found a command that will export the files as one big file but i want somthing that will keep the name and just put the outputs in another directory. Please put notes that describe what each part of the command does so i can modify it for my needs.

EDIT

This works:

```
for file in *.avi; do ffmpeg -i "$file" "${file%.avi}".webm; done
```

i just want to know what each part does so i can modify it for my needs.

Comment: Here is something to start with http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2017284. There are many redy made script, just google.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for file in *.avi; do ffmpeg -i "$file" "${file%.avi}".webm; done
```

This is a Bash "for loop" and is great for repeating tasks. Section by section:

#### `for file in *.avi;`

`file` will become the variable in the next section that will refer to each particular avi in the current directory for every successive loop.

What to customize:

- `file` could be re-named just about anything: `i` and `f` seem to be commonly used.
- You can change `*.avi` to whatever input format you need, such as `*.mkv`.

#### `do ffmpeg -i "$file" "${file%.avi}".webm;`

This will run `ffmpeg` for each avi. The part in curly braces is using [parameter expansion](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073) to remove the `.avi` part of the file name. For example, if an avi file is named `dog.avi`, then the output will be named `dog.webm`. If you simply use `"$file.webm"` for the output, then the output would end up as `dog.avi.webm`.

What to customize:

- You can add any `ffmpeg` options as usual.
- The `%.` part should use the same extension as in the `for file in` section, or you could change `%.avi` to `%.*` as a wildcard.
- `.webm` can be changed to whatever output container format you need.

If you want the new files to be outputted to a directory named `newvids`, then make the new directory and change the command to: `"newvids/${file%.avi}.webm"`

## `done`

This tells the loop that the command has finished, and now `$file` can refer to the next avi.